# Can skewness happen for r/w operations on scylla/cassandra cluster if phone number is used as primary key for the table?

Tags: cassandra, scylla

I am running a spark job which populates a table in scylla. The primary key in the table is of long type and it essentially contains phone numbers. If we talk about potential values of this field, it will definitely not be uniform since most of the phone numbers are concentrated between 9-12 digits.

As for my scylla configuration, its a single cluster with 3 nodes with replication factor as 3. My question is will read/write operations be skewed per node since primary key itself is skewed or will scylla choose the node after hashing the primary key which will make operations uniform?

I have seen that number of operations sometimes jump for a particular node but I want to be 100% sure before taking any steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The node for a partition is determined by the Murmur3 hash of the primary key.

For example, the phone number `920-458-3834` gets hashed to a token of `3485763808729355786`, and ends up being written to the node responsible for a token range that includes `3485763808729355786`.

Maybe the next phone number is similar to that one, say `920-458-3835`.  This gets hashed as `-6305759902789073081`, and in a large cluster will likely be written to a different node.

> seen that number of operations sometimes jump for a particular node

Not sure about the cluster or app setup, but it's possible that this could be a coordinator node.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer, is that using a phone number as the partition key is perfectly fine. It indeed goes through a hash function to generate a "token", and the phone numbers become uniform in this token steps.

In addition to what Aaron explained in the accepted answer that applies to any cluster size (basically that the partition key gets hashed), but in your case, a cluster with N=3 nodes and RF=3, the situation is even simpler: In such a cluster, each partition gets written to **all three nodes** - it needs to be written to three nodes because RF=3, but there are only three nodes in the cluster. So no matter what data you write, it needs to  go to all three nodes, and no matter which data you read, it can be read from any of the three nodes.

If you see one specific node more loaded then others, it might be a transient random thing, or perhaps your application is overusing this specific node as a **coordinator** (sending it all the requests) because the driver is misconfigured or something (?).